# How to stop change in single branch triggering multiple pipelines in azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, triggers, azure-pipelines

I want to map different branches with different azure pipelines in 1-1 fashion. But a change in single branch is triggering multiple pipelines.

How to prevent this? How to configure single pipeline with single branch and its application.yml file?

Comment: Why? If you want different behaviors based on branch, you can do that from a single pipeline via conditions. Please provide more detail about your pipeline structure and what you're looking to accomplish in different scenarios.

Comment: @DanielMann yes I need to configure different pipeline for different team members to build from their branches. They should be able to do manual run from their pipeline of their respective branch and also the build must get triggered as soon as they check-in some code, so I need 1 to 1 connection between a pipeline and build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can override the trigger

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works like magic

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) to do that.

What you can do is just specify in your YAML files which branch should trigger each pipeline, like this:

```
trigger:
  - master
```

Comment: It's not working like that. The application.yml file is in the branch, so if put trigger: - branch_name, then that application.yml file is only connected to the branch, as soon as that branch has some code checked in, it is triggering multiple pipelines. How to specify the pipeline name in application.yml